# capture camera input at certain point without first draw to canvas

Tags: html, canvas, base64, webcam-capture

I am creating an app that capture the web-cam at a certain point(when an event is triggered), like taking a snapshot of the camera and encode the snapshot to base64. But looking at the example online, they first draw that snapshot to a canvas and then convert that canvas to base64. Is there a way to skip "drawing to canvas" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, canvas is the only possible way to *read* pixels in a browser.

This is why the video stream must be drawn to the canvas first.

Comment: Similar question. Can't you just skip the use of the Video tag?